# PHP login script with authentication, blocking users from accessing a specific page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login script which checks if the authority id is 5 = admin, 6 = employee, or 7 = student.

Please check below:

```
// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){   
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "main.php"
$_SESSION["myusername"] = $myusername;
$_SESSION["mypassword"] = $mypassword;

while($count = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                              //echo $row['Username'];
                              //echo $row['access_level'];

                              if ($count['AuthorityId']== 5) {
                              //add custom content here for this user access level
                              header("location: adminpage.php");
                              exit();
                              } // end of if

  else if ($count['AuthorityId']== 6 ){
  //add custom content here for this user access level
    header("location: employeepage.php");
     exit();
  } // end of else if
  else{
    header("location: studentpage.php");
     exit();
      }

} // end of while 
}
else if( $myusername == '' || $mypassword == '' ){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert("There are empty fields!");
</script>'; 
}
else {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Wrong Username or Password")
</script>';
}
?>
```

When the user is an admin, he then goes to adminpage.php, but when I would directly put the url for employeepage.php, the user can access it. How can I restrict users from accessing other pages? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the authority in another session variable like so:

```
if ($count['AuthorityId']== 5) {
    //add custom content here for this user access level
    $_SESSION['authority'] = 5;
    header("location: adminpage.php");
    exit();
} // end of if
```

And then use:

```
if($_SESSION['authority'] != 5){
    die();
    // Or something more useful like a redirect
}
```

On restricted pages.

Comment: Hi may I ask, I used this: if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && $_SESSION['authority'] != 6){
    //$_POST['myusername'] = $_SESSION['myusername'];
      header("location: ../index.php");
   exit();

Comment: You don't need to test the username, just the authority. Also ensure you have `session_start()` above the statement.